# Странная работа jquery validate

Tags: jquery

```
// validation options
options = {
    rules: {
        'email': { required: true, email: true },
        'password': { required: true, minlength: 6 },
        'pass_check': { equalTo: '#password'},
        'name': { required: true},
        'captcha': { required: true}
    },
    messages: {
        'email': { required: 'Укажите email',
            email: 'Укажите правильный email'},
        'password': { required: 'Укажите пароль',
            minlength: 'Длина пароля должна быть 6 и более символов'},
        'pass_check': { equalTo: 'Пароль не совпадает' },
        'name': { required: 'Укажите логин'},
        'captcha': { required: 'Введите код'}
    },
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'error-span',
    highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
        $(element).removeClass(errorClass);
        $(element).parents('.block').addClass('error');
    }
};

$('#reg_form').validate(options);
```

Следующий код делает валидацию соответствующей формы. Суть в том, что у первых трех полей валидация проходит нормально, а имя и капча почему-то не хочет обрабатывать. В чем причина?
форма:

```
<form method="POST" action="" id="reg_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div class="enter-site-right">
        <h3 class="mb20">Еще не зарегистрированы?</h3>
        <div class="block email">
            <div class="block-left">
                <p>E-Mail:</p>
            </div> <!-- block-left -->
            <div class="block-right">
                <input type="text" name="email" value="{$params.email|escape}" onblur="validate_data('email',this.value)" />
                    <span class="error-span">
                    </span>
            </div> <!-- block-right -->
        </div> <!-- block -->
        <div class="block login">
            <div class="block-left">
                <p>Логин:</p>
            </div> <!-- block-left -->
            <div class="block-right">
                <input type="text" name="name" value="{$params.name|escape}" onblur="validate_data('login',this.value)"/>
                    <span class="error-span"></span>          
            </div> <!-- block-right -->
        </div> <!-- block -->
        <div class="block nickname">
            <div class="block-left">
                <p>Ник (подпись для форума):</p>
            </div> <!-- block-left -->
            <div class="block-right">
                <input type="text" name="nickname" value="{$params.nickname|escape}" onblur="validate_data('nickname',this.value)"/>
                    <span class="error-span">
                    </span>
            </div> <!-- block-right -->
        </div> <!-- block -->
        <div class="block{if $errors.password} error{/if}">
            <div class="block-left">
                <p>Пароль:</p>
            </div> <!-- block-left -->
            <div class="block-right">
                <input type="password" name="password" value="{$params.password|escape}" id="password" />
                {if $errors.password == 'length'}<span class="error-span">Длина пароля должна быть 6 и более символов</span>{/if}
            </div> <!-- block-right -->
        </div> <!-- block -->
        <div class="block{if $errors.pass_check} error{/if}">
            <div class="block-left">
                <p>Повторите пароль:</p>
            </div> <!-- block-left -->
            <div class="block-right">
                <input type="password" name="pass_check" />
                {if $errors.pass_check}<span class="error-span">Повторите правильно пароль</span>{/if}
            </div> <!-- block-right -->
        </div> <!-- block -->
        <div class="block{if $errors.recaptcha} error{/if}">
            <div class="block-left">
                <p>Анти-спам:</p>
            </div> <!-- block-left -->
            <div class="block-right">
                <div style="line-height: 26px; color: #808080; margin: 0 0 20px 0;">
                    <span>{$captcha}</span>
                    <input type="text" name="captcha"/>
                    {if $errors.recaptcha}<span class="error-span">Введите правильный код</span>{/if}
                </div>
            </div> <!-- block-right -->
        </div> <!-- block -->
        <div class="block">
            <div class="block-left">
                &nbsp;
            </div> <!-- block-left -->
            <div class="block-right">
                <div class="h0 mb10">
                   <input type="submit" value="Зарегистрироваться"   class="auth-search-2 f16"/>
                </div> <!-- h0 mb10 -->
            </div> <!-- block-right -->
        </div> <!-- block -->
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Укажите для них `minlength` и `maxlength`.

Comment: А сама форма-то где?

Comment: добавил форму выше